# *.domain.local in my /etc/hosts

Tags: ubuntu, domain, hosts

Can I set access to all subdomains in my local domain in `etc/hosts` file?

Like

```
127.0.0.1       localhost *.domain.local
```

Now it looks like

```
127.0.0.1       localhost domain.local mail.domain.local web.domain.local other.domain.local ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, wildcards are a DNS lookup thing; trying to do the same thing in your `/etc/hosts` doesn't work.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant do that in your hosts file. You should though be able to setup [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) quite easilly to do this. Adding

```
address=/domain.local/127.0.0.1
```

to the dnsmasq.conf file should do what you want.